# Phrase for a test to make sure nothing happens

Tags: phrases

I'm sure I've heard this phrase said before, but I can't seem to remember it or find it by searching.

A positive test is one where you make sure something specific happens - I hit a button and make sure it makes a noise, which is what I expect.

A negative test is one where you make sure something specific doesn't happen - I hit a button again and make sure that it doesn't explode, which it used to before the most recent round of changes.

But there's a term for a kind of test to make sure that absolutely nothing happens at all - perhaps that the button is completely disconnected, or that after changing a setting in software no changes are allowed to be made in a certain area. What's the name of that kind of test?

Comment: "My name is my passport. *Verify* me." –Sneakers 1992

Comment: Is 'null test' used hereabouts?

Comment: @Mazura they had advanced audio voice recognition, but no cameras to see if their mouths were actually moving or if they were playing a tape. Strange priorities.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's the phrase, can't believe I forgot it. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Assuming hereabouts is the programming world (or audio engineering, mathematics, etc.). In mine, it's verification. *Verify that the power is off.*

Comment: A catchall for this sort of thing is an *isolation test*. Perturb one thing and check that the other thing is unaffected.

Comment: Well, there's "smoke test", for turning something and seeing if it catches fire or some such.  Used figuratively in programming for a basic preliminary test to see if anything works.

Answer (score 1):

It's an **invalid test**.

In most cases, even if the button were completely disconnected it would be a positive test or a negative test.  In the case where the test is somehow flawed as you describe, then it's an invalid test.

Other common terminology may include: incomplete test, insufficient test, incompatible test, or the test is considered null and void.